# How can i make responsive Sqlite Database with android?

Tags: android, sqlite

Let me say my requirement whenever i insert the some value in sqlitedatabase i need to populate recyclerview instantly how can i do this !! well i have read i can be done through contentprovider or loadercallback already i have done half the project with sqliteonehelper class where i have done all query according to my requirement only thing missing is instantly i could not populate recyclerview how can i do this am bit confused with contentprovider ,loadercallback, content observer i have read in one post i cannot be achieved without contentprovider do i really need provider for responsive changes in db or can it be achieve without this ! let me post what i have done so far:

This is sqliteonehelper class:

```
public class Account_DB extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 4;
        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "account.db";
        Context mcontext;
        SQLiteDatabase db;
        public static final Uri DB_TABLE_ACCOUNTS_URI = Uri
                .parse("sqlite://" + "xx" + "/" + DATABASE_NAME);
        public Account_SF_DB(android.content.Context context) {

            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            this.mcontext=context;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            String CREATE_TABLE_ACCOUNT = "CREATE TABLE " + Model_Account.Accunt_Table + "("
                    + Model_Account.id + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,"
                    + Model_Account.company_groups + " TEXT, "
                    + Model_Account.Parent_company + " TEXT, "
                    + Model_Account.Company_name + " TEXT, "
                    + Model_Account.Company_type + " TEXT ,"
                    + Model_Account.Address_line1 + " TEXT ,"
                    + Model_Account.Address_line2 + " TEXT ,"
                    + Model_Account.Address_line3 + " TEXT ,"
                    + Model_Account.State + " TEXT ,"
                    + Model_Account.State_id + " INTEGER ,"
                    + Model_Account.City + " TEXT ,"
                    + Model_Account.CityID + " INTEGER ,"
                    + Model_Account.pincode + " TEXT ,"
                    + Model_Account.Landline1 + " TEXT ,"
                    + Model_Account.Landline2 + " TEXT ,"
                    + Model_Account.Url + " TEXT ,"
                    + Model_Account.Email_id + " TEXT ,"
                    + Model_Account.Industry + " TEXT ,"
                    + Model_Account.IndustryID + " INTEGER ,"
                    + Model_Account.companyname_id + " INTEGER ,"
                    + Model_Account.Account_manager + " TEXT ,"
                    + Model_Account.Account_managerid + " INTEGER ,"
                    + Model_Account.Region + " TEXT ,"
                    + Model_Account.regionid + " INTEGER , "
                    + Model_Account.Muti_location + " TEXT ,"
                    + Model_Account.mutilocationid + " INTEGER , "
                    + Model_Account.spinner_state_position + " INTEGER ,"
                    + Model_Account.parent_company_spinner_pos + " INTEGER ,"
                    + Model_Account.city_spinner_pos + " INTEGER ,"
                    + Model_Account.industry_spinner_pos + " INTEGER ,"
                    + Model_Account.acm_spinner_pos + " INTEGER ,"
                    + Model_Account.region_spinner_pos + " INTEGER ,"
                    + Model_Account.Account_ID + " INTEGER"
                    + ");";

            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_ACCOUNT);


        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Model_Account.Accunt_Table);
            onCreate(db);
        }

        public void onInsert(Model_Account accountobj) {
            db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues contentobj = new ContentValues();
            contentobj.put(Model_Account.company_groups, accountobj.getCompany_group());
            contentobj.put(Model_Account.Parent_company, accountobj.getParent_company());
            contentobj.put(Model_Account.Company_name, accountobj.getCompany_name());
            contentobj.put(Model_Account.Company_type, accountobj.getCompany_type());
            contentobj.put(Model_Account.Address_line1, accountobj.getAddrss_line1());
            contentobj.put(Model_Account.Address_line2, accountobj.getAddrss_line2());
            contentobj.put(Model_Account.Address_line3, accountobj.getAddrss_line3());
            contentobj.put(Model_Account.State, accountobj.getState());
            contentobj.put(Model_Account.State_id, accountobj.getStateid());
            contentobj.put(Model_Account.City, accountobj.getCity());
            contentobj.put(Model_Account.CityID, accountobj.getCityid());
            contentobj.put(Model_Account.pincode, accountobj.getPincode());
            contentobj.put(Model_Account.Landline1, accountobj.getLandline1());
            contentobj.put(Model_Account.Landline2, accountobj.getLandline2());
            contentobj.put(Model_Account.Url, accountobj.getUrl());
            contentobj.put(Model_Account.Email_id, accountobj.getEmailid());
            contentobj.put(Model_Account.Industry, accountobj.getIndusty());
            contentobj.put(Model_Account.IndustryID, accountobj.getIndustryid());
            contentobj.put(Model_Account.Account_manager, accountobj.getAccount_manager());
            contentobj.put(Model_Account.Account_managerid, accountobj.getAccountmanager());
            contentobj.put(Model_Account.Region, accountobj.getRegion());
            contentobj.put(Model_Account.regionid, accountobj.getRegionID());
            contentobj.put(Model_Account.Muti_location, accountobj.getMulti_location());
            contentobj.put(Model_Account.mutilocationid, accountobj.getMulti_location());
            contentobj.put(Model_Account.companyname_id, accountobj.getCompanyname());
            contentobj.put(Model_Account.Account_ID, accountobj.getAccountID());
            contentobj.put(Model_Account.spinner_state_position,accountobj.getSpinner_state_pos());
            contentobj.put(Model_Account.parent_company_spinner_pos,accountobj.getParent_company_pos());
            contentobj.put(Model_Account.city_spinner_pos,accountobj.getCity_pos());
            contentobj.put(Model_Account.industry_spinner_pos,accountobj.getIndustry_pos());
            contentobj.put(Model_Account.acm_spinner_pos,accountobj.getAcm_spinner_position());
            contentobj.put(Model_Account.region_spinner_pos, accountobj.getRegion_spinner_posion());
            db.insert(Model_Account.Accunt_Table, null, contentobj);
              db.close();
        }
  public List<Model_Account> list() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + Model_Account.Accunt_Table;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        List<Model_Account> listobj = new ArrayList<Model_Account>();
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Model_Account modelobj = new Model_Account();
                modelobj.setID(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Model_Account.id)));
                modelobj.setCompany_group(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Model_Account.company_groups)));
                modelobj.setState(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Model_Account.State)));

                listobj.add(modelobj);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        return listobj;


    }
```

This is the activity where am implementing this insert method:

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getBaseContext());


        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, params[0], new JSONObject(),
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        String server_response = response.toString();
                        try {
                            JSONObject json_object = new JSONObject(server_response);
                            JSONArray json_array = new JSONArray(json_object.getString("AccountPageLoadAccountListResult"));
                            for (int i = 0; i < json_array.length(); i++) {
                                Model_Account modelobjs = new Model_Account();
                                JSONObject json_arrayJSONObject = json_array.getJSONObject(i);
                                modelobjs.setCompany_group(json_arrayJSONObject.getString("CompanyName"));
                                modelobjs.setState(json_arrayJSONObject.getString("Region"));
                                modelobjs.setAccountID(json_arrayJSONObject.getInt("AccountID"));
                                account_xx_db.InsertorUpdate(modelobjs);
                                accountListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



                            }
                        }  catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });
        queue.add(jsonObjRequest);
       return null;
    }
```

This is where am setting list function from sqliteonehelper class to recyclerview adapter:

```
  listobj = account_sf_db.list();
                accountListAdapter = new AccountListAdapter(listobj, getApplicationContext());
                recyclerView.setAdapter(accountListAdapter);
```

But i could not get instantly i need to go back and come again to that activity to see that newly updated value how can i get it instantly after i insert into db this is problem am facing can somebody tell me the solution for this!!

Comment: are you trying to update your recyclerview after getting the json result ?

Comment: yaaa thats what am doing

Answer (score 1):

You are dumping your all codes and it's really tough to view all, But what I can suggest is create a method like here

```
public void updateList(List<Model_Account> listobj){
  accountListAdapter = new AccountListAdapter(listobj, getApplicationContext());
  recyclerView.setAdapter(accountListAdapter);
  accountListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Then call this method after you retrieve the Json data, That means inside `onResponse` Or where ever you want to update the listlike here

```
@Override
  public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
   //other Codes
    updateList(listobj)
}
```

Comment: i have done i could not pick id for first time getting null pointer exception

Comment: what id ? and first time only or each time ? Are you able to get others beside id ?

Comment: noo nothing what am trying to do is am inserting the json response into sqlite db and trying to populate recyclerview from that value from quering it for the first after inserting i could not pick id and value both i could not pick anything but once i go and visit again to acitivity its working fine

Comment: are you using cursoradapter ? and are sure your data are inserted successfully ? Just want to update the list after inserting them ?

Comment: yaaa  thats what i need can you tell me how can i do this

Comment: you need to set `getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);` in the activity or fragment and implement `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>` have you done this in your project ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106183/discussion-between-yog-and-shree-krishna).